# Cycles rendering stopped

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

[Cycles render (animation) stopped without finishing. What could be the reason ? I didn't turn off the computer while its animating. 
I'm a real beginner for blender, please be kind enough to guide me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Fnm.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Fnm.png)

Answer (score 1):

You Must have pressed the cancel button in the render tab or <kbd>Esc</kbd> accidentally.

[image]

Comment: or pressed [ESC]